# typescript: generics and any

Tags: javascript, typescript

Please see the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=export%20class%20Greeter%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3a%20T;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28message%3a%20T%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20=%20message;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.greeting;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IAAA%7B%0D%0A%09test%3a%28id%3astring%29=%3E%20Greeter%3Cstring%3E;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AAA%20implements%20IAAA%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09test%28id%3astring%29%3aGreeter%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//return%20new%20Greeter%3Cstring%3E%28%22Hello,%20world%22%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Greeter%3Cnumber%3E%28123%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

```
export class Greeter<T> {
    greeting: T;
    constructor(message: T) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return this.greeting;
    }
}

export interface IAAA{
    test:(id:string)=> Greeter<string>;
}

class AAA implements IAAA{

    test(id:string):Greeter<any> {
        //return new Greeter<string>("Hello, world");
        return new Greeter<number>(123);
    }
}
```

this doesn't give any error. the interface declaration is expecting a typed object of `string`, but how `any` which is of type number satisfies it.? I would expect an error that class doesn't implement the interface as the interface requires a stricter type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin either of the following would be an error :

```
class AAA implements IAAA{    
    test(id:string):Greeter<number> { // Error
        return new Greeter<number>(123);
    }
}

// or let ts infer : 

class AAA implements IAAA{
    test(id:string){                    // Error
        return new Greeter<number>(123);
    }
}
```

Now the reason the following compiles:

```
export interface IAAA{
    test:(id:string)=> Greeter<string>;
}

class AAA implements IAAA{    
    test(id:string):Greeter<any> {        
        return new Greeter<number>(123);
    }
}
```

is that you are specifically telling TS that I return a `Greeter<any>` and `any` is compatible with both `number` (what your return) and `string` (what the interface expects)

Comment: still bit confused. please see a followup qn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377759/static-typting-and-generic-contravariance