# static typting and generic contravariance

Tags: generics, typescript

Please see the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IId%7B%0D%0A%09id%3a%28%29=%3E%20string;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Service%20%7B%0D%0A%09get%28id%3astring%29%3a%20Promise%3CIId%3E%20%7B%20return%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IUser%20extends%20IId%7B%0D%0A%09name%3a%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IUserService%7B%0D%0A%09test%3a%28d%3astring%29%20=%3E%20Promise%3CIUser%3E;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20UserService%20implements%20IUserService%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor%28private%20srv%3a%20Service%29%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09test%28d%3astring%29%3aPromise%3CIUser%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.srv.get%28%22%22%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) It is in typescript, but due to the similarity with C# may be it is applicable to it too.

```
export class Promise<T> {
}
export interface IId{
    id:()=> string;
}
class Service {
    get(id:string): Promise<IId> { return }
}

export interface IUser extends IId{
    name: string
}

export interface IUserService{
    test:(d:string) => Promise<IUser>;
}

class UserService implements IUserService{

    constructor(private srv: Service){}

    test(d:string):Promise<IUser> {
        return this.srv.get("");
    }
}
```

say, I have a framework service function `get` which returns a promise of type `IId`. In my custom class, I have a method, which is defined to return a promise of type `IUser`. I made a mistake by returning `this.srv.get("")`, which returns `Promise<IId>`. But that should not be compatible with `Promise<IUser>` as IUser is expecting a `name` field. Why there is no error?

I am not familiar with C# generics, and is this what called `contravariance`. Read some articles but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: The similarity with C# being... that they both use curly braces?

Comment: no, it is from MS and influenced by the same designers. Also, in the discussion boards and all, many refer to C#. It is also fully supported by Visual Studio, and work as a client side language counterpart of C#.

Comment: While Anders worked on both C# and TypeScript, he also worked on Delphi and Turbo Pascal. Try not to read too much into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Promise` type is empty *and* doesn't use `T`, both of which are really big problems. TypeScript uses a structural type system, so an empty type is a supertype of all types, and a generic type that doesn't use its type arguments will effectively not have type checking on those type parameters.

If `Promise` used its type argument, you would see an error:

```
export class Promise<T> {
    foo: T; // <- ADDED
}
export interface IId{
    id:()=> string;
}
class Service {
    get(id:string): Promise<IId> { return }
}

export interface IUser extends IId{
    name: string
}

export interface IUserService{
    test:(d:string) => Promise<IUser>;
}

class UserService implements IUserService{

    constructor(private srv: Service){}

    test(d:string):Promise<IUser> {
        // ERROR
        return this.srv.get("");
    }
}
```

Trying to use C# (a nominal type system) as a reference point for TypeScript (a structural type system) isn't going to be very productive.